# What is the signal-noise model of laser induced fluorescence?

Tags: signal, noise, signal-processing, signal-theory

The following image is an example of a fluorescence signal trace from the photomultiplier tube detector (PMT). Each spike represents one fluorescently labeled cell.

[image]

This signal model is definitely not additive white Gaussian, although the noise term is Gaussian. The signals are low variance but the point is that when the signal amplitude increases, the noise variance rapidly decreases. In the given example, above the intensity value of \$0.6\$ all three Gaussian signals are almost noise free. Around \$0.4-0.5\$ intensity of the noise is reduced but can be seen if zoomed. Below \$0.4\$ the noise is significantly apparent.

> How can this signal-noise relation be properly modeled? For example for additive noise we have $$x[n]=s[n]+w[n]$$ where \$x\$ is the received signal \$s\$ is the error free signal and \$w\$ is the Gaussian noise.

My aim is to simulate such signals in Matlab using a theoretical model. However, I was not able to see and/or find any model via google search or on some related books.

The physics behind this is due to detection of laser signal via photodiodes or PMTs. I was thinking that the noise source was probably the quantum noise but I am not sure because for the quantum noise, the noise variance does not decrease when the total number of photons \$N\$ increases. Instead it increases as \$\sqrt N\$.

What I tried was dividing the noise values by \$k+s[n]^2\$ before adding to the signal, where \$k\$ is some constant. I did this over additive Gaussian noise model. The results were okay. But I am not able to justify this theoretically. It is just my intuitive understanding.

**Sources:**

https://www.cut.ac.cy/faculties/fet/mem/research/research-units-and-laboratories/biolisys/research/imaging/cytometry/?languageId=1

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser-induced_fluorescence

Comment: You may find more people knowing about that stuff on dsp.se

Comment: @PlasmaHH I have doubts about that but it may be a good idea. The problem is that such models either do not exist on DSP books, or I have not yet seen any.

Comment: Interesting question!  How do you really know what the noise variance is?  Do you take a large number of the above waveforms, average them together then use that as the real signal.  Subtract that real signal from each of the sets and then look at the residuals?

Comment: @MikeP I just take millions of samples from the baseline, where no signal (Gaussian peak) is present and I calcualte the emprical variance from these samples. So the variance that I mention is actually the variance of the noise where no signal is present. Since the signal is correlated to the noise, the actual variance is dependent on the number and shape of the Gaussian signals.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my question then is how do you know how much noise you have during the signal?  How do you separate the two or measure how correlated they might be?

Comment: I actually dont and I am wondering this:) So in Matlab I create noise free Gaussian almost exactly the ones that are similar to those in the figure. Just low variance Gaussian signals. Then I also have the model of the noise so I just create random samples from the noise and add it to the Gaussian signals. The resulting noise added signal has noise in the Gaussian signals. One can see this visually.. However, the signals given in the image are noise free when the signal is high enough. So they do not look similar. From this observation, it is then clear that the noise is correlated

Comment: Understood!  That is an interesting problem, I think you'll probably have to create a new noise model, as I've never seen one in the literature.  Something about the physics of the PMT seems to be nonlinear in that sense.

Comment: @MikeP Yes. I really didnt understand this at first. Because, I was expecting to have a noise term which is independent of the signal and is Gaussian. In the literature I saw similar signals which are becoming error free at higher amplitudes, so at this point I realized that I was not in a dream, or at least I have some dream mates:)

Comment: You say the signal is (nearly) noise-free when fluoresence is present. But your chart shows very different amplitudes from one peak to the next. Are you sure the variation in peak heights aren't a form of noise?

Comment: @ThePhoton I am 100\$\%\$ sure that the different amplitudes from peak to peak are not related to the noise. They are mostly related to the amount of fluoresence injected into the cell. So not all cells have the same amount therefore when the laser is directed to these cells, the amount of detection via photodectectors also vary. These variations are due to the laser intensity at the detector and have nothing to do with noise.

Comment: Are the different amplitudes of signal (related to the amount of fluoresence injected into the cell) the noise you're trying to model? _or_ is it the noise on top of this - from the PMT what you're attempting to model? If it's the PMT look at this https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/etd/PMT_handbook_v3aE.pdf

Comment: @DDuck Different amplitudes are not a problem. I can create them in Matlab easily. The problem is the model of noise and its correlation to the Gaussian signals..

Comment: I suggest this link to cbeleites's answer to a question involving laser-excited Raman spectroscopy: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164713/figuring-out-signal-to-noise-ratio-of-spectral-data/194247#194247 and this golden oldie paper: N.J. Dovichi, J.C. Martin, J.H. Jett, M. Trkula, R.A. Keller, "Laser-Induced Fluorescence of Flowing Samples as an Approach to Single-Molecule Detection in Liquids", Anal. Chem.,56 (1984) 348-354. There are thousands of laser-induced (aka, laser excited) fluorescence papers, but newer research papers tend not to dwell on the fundamentals.